# Unable to bind custom MvvmCross Views

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have created two custom Android Views that I would like to bind to properties in my data model. When I run the app, the properties are definitely not bound and I see errors such as `MvxBind:Error:106.21 View type not found - md5b46e1450448c30667827ca3b24581c6a.NavigationListView` in my logs.

I also originally had the same issue with `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`, which I was able to fix by adding the assembly to `AndroidViewAssemblies` in Setup.cs. I tried doing the same with my custom views, to no avail. My `AndroidViewAssemblies` looks like this:

```
protected override IList<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies
{
    get
    {
        var assemblies = base.AndroidViewAssemblies;
        assemblies.Add(typeof(DrawerLayout).Assembly);
        assemblies.Add(typeof(NavigationListView).Assembly);
        return assemblies;
    }
}
```

I did notice that for `DrawerLayout`, MvxBind included the full namespace in the log, but for my custom views it is using an md5 hash instead of the namespace, which I believe is related to the problem I am seeing.

This was definitely working a few days ago, but it still doesn't work after reverting back to the code I was using when I know it was working . This leads me to believe that I have a configuration issue of some sort.

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I did install StyleCop and update Reshaper to version 8.2 since this last worked, but I am skeptical of those breaking my custom views.

What could be going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: this just looks like it's part of Xam's latest breaking changes. Try using the `Register` attribute to set the java class name of your view to the old style java class name - slightly more readable and predictable than `md5b46e1450448c30667827ca3b24581c6a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Stuart suggested, this is a part of [Xamarin's breaking changes](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37277/stable-release-xamarin-android-5-1-0-breaking-changes-new-features-and-bug-fixes) in Xamarin 5.1.

I had to do two things to fix this:

- I had to add `[Register("com/example/namespace/CustomViewName")]` to my custom Views to fix those.
- I updated to MvvmCross 3.5.1 to fix binding for MvvmCross controls (e.g. `MvxListView`).